# how to do double line breaks in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me figure out how to do double line breaks for my paragraph?

```
<script>
var mails = [{"subject”:”Lorem ipsum”, "body”:”Lorem ipsum\n” +
"\n" +
“Lorum ipsum dolor sit amen, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a liqua.\n” +
"\n" +
“Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea comoodo consequat.\n” +
"\n" +
“Duis aute irere dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate relit esse cillim dolore eu fuggita nulla pariatur.\n” +
"\n" + “Excepteur,,\n” +
"[ADD YOUR SIGNATURE HERE]"} , {"subject”:”Lorem ipsum” , "body”:”Lorem ipsum,\n” +
"\n" +
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \n" +
"\n" +
"Sincerely,\n" + "[YOUR NAME]"} 

function random() {
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mails.length - 0));
window.location.href ="mailto:?subject="+mails[randomnumber].subject+"&body="+mails[randomnumber].body;
}
</script>

<li><a onclick="random()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
```

(I removed my actual message/email for privacy purposes) But I'm not sure how to add 2 line breaks in between sentences.

Comment: have you tried `"\n\n"`?

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work for me, I also tried \r\n

Comment: Seems problem in your double quote!!!

Comment: @Omar Sorry could you clarify exactly how I can change it

Comment: Some of your quotes are plain double quotes, and some are formatted quotes, which are actually different characters.  That's probably what Omar meant, although I don't know if it's your underlying problem.

Comment: They may be a byproduct of using a word processor to edit your text, but worst case, you can just copy one that is straight up and down and paste it in place of the angled ones.  Still I don't know if that's the basic problem here.

Answer (score 0):

See difference regarding a `double quote`, replace all your `”` with `"`

```js
var msg= "Hello\n\n" + "user12098172";
console.log(msg)
```

And for `”`

```js
var msg= "Hello\n\n” + "user12098172";
console.log(msg)
```

So replace all your `”` with `"`

Comment: I just tried this, unfortunately it still didn't work for me :( I did: "Lorem ipsum,\n\n" +
"Lorem ipsum...."

Comment: My code is too long to post here, but currently it is the same exact code as the first block that Aaron Chen posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your quote, ("") is good and recognizable by javascript engine, while (“”) is not. Be sure to change back to English input typing when you're coding will solve your problem.

I believe this is what you want(I replaced all your “ and ” with "):

```
<script>
var mails = [{"subject":"Lorem ipsum", "body":"Lorem ipsum\n" +
"\n" +
"Lorum ipsum dolor sit amen, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a liqua.\n" +
"\n" +
"Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea comoodo consequat.\n" +
"\n" +
"Duis aute irere dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate relit esse cillim dolore eu fuggita nulla pariatur.\n" +
"\n" + "Excepteur,,\n" +
"[ADD YOUR SIGNATURE HERE]"} , {"subject":"Lorem ipsum" , "body":"Lorem ipsum,\n" +
"\n" +
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \n" +
"\n" +
"Sincerely,\n" + "[YOUR NAME]"}]
function random() {
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mails.length - 0));
window.location.href ="mailto:?subject="+mails[randomnumber].subject+"&body="+mails[randomnumber].body;
}
</script>

<li><a onclick="random()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></a></li>
```

Or you can just test it by console log your mail variable in browser console:

```
var mails = [{"subject":"Lorem ipsum", "body":"Lorem ipsum\n" +
"\n" +
"Lorum ipsum dolor sit amen, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a liqua.\n" +
"\n" +
"Ut enim ad minim venom, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea comoodo consequat.\n" +
"\n" +
"Duis aute irere dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate relit esse cillim dolore eu fuggita nulla pariatur.\n" +
"\n" + "Excepteur,,\n" +
"[ADD YOUR SIGNATURE HERE]"} , {"subject":"Lorem ipsum" , "body":"Lorem ipsum,\n" +
"\n" +
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.  \n" +
"\n" +
"Sincerely,\n" + "[YOUR NAME]"}]

console.log(mails)
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, I copied and pasted this exact code into my IDE but it unfortunately still didn't work!

Comment: @user12098172 try the second part of my code in your browser (open a chrome browser, press F12, copy and paste the code, press enter), at least it solves the "mails" object's problem.

Comment: In your posted code "<li><a onclick="random()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>" should actually be "<li><a onclick="random()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></a></li>" I guess,(you have an </i> in your list tag, which should not be there) I've modified it in my first chunk of code.